# PHP acts wierdly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, iteration

OK so i literally don't know what the title is because to me there shouldn't be a problem here.

I'm trying to build a SQL query and the only way i can do that is by adding upon a string OR statments after the first ID=.

Since i can't have an OR statment on inbetween ID= X, i thought i'd make a simple thing that just counts to 1 then every iteration after 1 it simple puts "OR" before the next number.

This works fine the second iteration but the third and fourth it skips adding OR in between numbers so it becomes ID = 123 OR 56 43 12.

The codes part of a bigger thing so the } before the last } is ending of anotehr loop.

```
       $count=0;
      while($resultArr = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
          if($count>=1)
          {
              echo "IN COUNT IF<br>";
              $sqlQuery .= " OR ";
          }
          else  $count++;
          echo "COUNT= ". $count . "<br>";
          $sqlQuery .= " {$resultArr[0]} ";
          if (!$result) {
              die('Contact Admin! Invalid SQL query: ' . mysql_error());
          }
      }
   }
   # lägg till sista biten och kolla hur det ska sorteras
   $sqlQuery .= "AND post_status='publish' " . $this->returnSort();
   echo "DEBUG- buildKategoryQuery QUERY= <br>{$sqlQuery}<br>";
   return $sqlQuery;
```

}

This is the resulting Query after adding the last bit from echo:

COUNT= 1

IN COUNT IF

COUNT= 1

COUNT= 1

DEBUG- buildKategoryQuery QUERY=

SELECT post_title, guid, post_date, comment_count FROM `wp_posts` WHERE ID = 159 OR 595 187 AND post_status='publish'

So it looks like it basically says on third iteration that $count isn't equal or higher to 1 anymore but neither does it want to add to count. So it basically just skips the whole if/else statment...

EDIT:
Heres the whole function for those who asked

```
function buildKategoryQuery()
   {
       # första biten
       $sqlQuery = "SELECT post_title, guid, post_date, comment_count FROM
       `wp_posts` WHERE ID =";      # "{$resultArr[0]} AND post_status='publish' ";

       # börja loopa och kolla vilka kategorier att leta efter
       foreach ($this->catMap as $key => $value) {
           # kolla ifall kategori är "vald" och isåfall hämta den
           if(!$this->kategoriArr[$key]) continue;
           # hämta post IDs
           $katCommand = "SELECT object_id FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE
           term_taxonomy_id=" . $value;
           $result = $this->sql->query($katCommand);
          // echo "number of rows returned for {$key}-{$value}: ".$result->num_rows . "</br>"; // debug - visa rows och kategori, id
           if (!$result) {
               die('Contact Admin! Invalid SQL query: ' . mysql_error());
           }
           # bygg fullt kommand
           $count=0;
          while($resultArr = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
              if($count>=1)
              {
                  echo "IN COUNT IF<br>";
                  $sqlQuery .= " OR ";
              }
              else  $count++;
              echo "COUNT= ". $count . "<br>";
              $sqlQuery .= " {$resultArr[0]} ";
              if (!$result) {
                  die('Contact Admin! Invalid SQL query: ' . mysql_error());
              }
          }
       }
       # lägg till sista biten och kolla hur det ska sorteras
       $sqlQuery .= "AND post_status='publish' " . $this->returnSort();
       echo "DEBUG- buildKategoryQuery QUERY= <br>{$sqlQuery}<br>";
       return $sqlQuery;
   }
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a little more code (specifically, a few lines above where you set `$count` to 0?

Comment: Also, why are you only incrementing `$count` when `$count` is 0? Why not remove the else-clause and simply do `echo "COUNT= ". ++$count . "<br>";` instead?

Comment: I agree with @ChrisForrence, it seems that your `$result` gives nothing, and it loops in outer loop

Comment: Because i only need to increment it once, every iteration after that i will need an OR in my query. So i either need to increment it or add OR to the query.

Comment: `echo $katCommand`    ?

Comment: Yep, there's only one result retrieved each time, so `$count` keeps getting reset to 0.

Comment: That makes no sense why would it go back to 0 at every second iteration?               private $catMap=["demokrati"=>0, "ekonomi"=>0, "infrastruktur"=>0,
                                "revisioner"=>0, "okategoriserade"=>0, "motioner"=>0 ]; Its a map of different IDS, the value are just random digits...

Comment: How many rows get returned in `SELECT object_id FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE term_taxonomy_id=0`?

Comment: 0 there is no object_id 0 in wp_term_relationships

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you're trying to say, is [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp).

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 159 OR 595 OR 187` is invalid SQL; instead, it should be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 159 OR id = 595 OR id = 187`.

A shorter syntax would be using the `IN` operator: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (159, 595, 187)`.

Comment: I guess thatt will help but still wtf does it skip my if/else statment the third iteration for?

Comment: No SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 159 OR 595 OR 187 is not invalid. Works for me.

Comment: It may not be _invalid_ per se, but it won't return what you're intending. To highlight the issue, are you only getting results where the rows' ids are _only_ either 159, 595 or 187?

Comment: In `WHERE id = 159 OR 595`, `595` is evaluated as a boolean expression, which returns _true_ since it's not `0`, so you'll get no error... And all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to add the "OR"s is using an array:

```
$parts = array();
while($resultArr = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) { 
    $parts[] = $resultArr[0];
}

if( !empty( $parts ) ) {
    $sqlQuery .= "(" . implode( " OR ", $parts ) . ")";
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Regarding why your loop doesn't work as expected: You only increment your $count in the else case, not the if case where most iterations end up...

Comment: @odepax's answer is essentially the correct one.  Mine can help you with your PHP coding for the future but the real problem is the SQL statement itself. You should accept his answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

`$katCommand` runs during each iteration in the foreach loop, and `$count` gets reset to 0 as well. That's problematic when you're trying to add to an outer query and relying on that `$count` variable to determine whether or not to add "OR" to the WHERE clause.

Instead of running multiple SQL queries, you can combine everything into one single query:

```
<?php

function buildKategoryQuery()
{
    // Get valid categories (where the key exists in $this->kategoriArr)  
    $categories = array_filter($this->catMap, function ($value, $key) {
        return $this->kategoriArr[$key];
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

    $sql_category_list = implode(', ', array_unique(array_values($categories))) . ')';
    $sql_sort = $this->returnSort();

    $sqlQuery = <<<SQL
SELECT post_title, guid, post_date, comment_count 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN ({$sql_category_list})
)
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
{$sql_sort}
SQL;

    return $sqlQuery;
}
```